# In Google Sheets, how would you use the query formula to create two columns populated with data from a third column based on criteria of a fourth?

Tags: google-sheets

To all:

This is my first foray into using a forum for my specific question, so, please, let me know what additional information might be necessary. I am providing some information below; yet, if it is better in a different format, please, let me know.

I am attempting to use a query in Google Sheets to dynamically clean some data that is populated by another source rather than cleaning each time the data are updated.

I would like to have rows with only those ID occurring twice (i.e., once with a Pretest and once with a Posttest). Further, I need a column with the Value of the Pretest and a column with a Value of the Posttest; following, I would love the query to populate an additional column with the percent change pre-to-posttest.

I am flummoxed and cannot create this dynamic formula.

Please, let me know if there is anything more needed to help with this request.

Desired Data:

| ID | Pretest Value | Posttest Value | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0.50 | 0.25 | '#0.00' |
| 127 | 0.13 | 3.89 | '#0.00' |
| 129 | 2.00 | 0.62 | '#0.00' |
| 130 | 1.22 | 0.29 | '#0.00' |

Raw Data:

| ID | Test | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Pretest | 0.50 |
| 101 | Posttest | 0.25 |
| 127 | Posttest | 3.89 |
| 127 | Pretest | 0.13 |
| 129 | Pretest | 2.00 |
| 129 | Posttest | 0.62 |
| 130 | Pretest | 1.22 |
| 130 | Posttest | 0.29 |
| 133 | Pretest | 0.31 |
| 137 | Pretest | 3.13 |
| 138 | Posttest | 0.63 |
| 140 | Pretest | 1.20 |
| 141 | Pretest | 2.30 |
| 100 | Posttest | 0.75 |
| 126 | Pretest | 1.10 |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: If you will post a link to a spreadsheet containing your sample data above, I believe I can offer a one-formula solution that will provide you with Pre, Post and %Change including formatting of the final column per your post.

Comment: Here is a link to the Raw Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BtGE4UYouJ9VrIss5IsU6ugAtTUmldfbm6LWcm0oVcM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  query( 
    Sheet1!A1:C, 
    "select A, max(C) 
     where A is not null 
     group by A 
     pivot B", 
    1 
  ), 
  "select Col1, Col3, Col2 
   where Col2 is not null and Col3 is not null", 
  1 
)
```

To calculate the diff, put this formula next to the query result table in the same row as the query formula:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Diff"; 
    if(
      C2:C * B2:B, 
      C2:C - B2:B, 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```